# Picasso Dependency error when adding Map Box Dependency

Tags: java, android-studio, dependencies, mapbox, picasso

I'm getting an error from Picasso Dependency after I add Map Box Dependency.

My build.gradle map box code :

```
    //Map Box
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.0.0@aar')
            {
                transitive=true
            }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.27.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.27.0')
            {
                transitive = true
            }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-markerview-v9:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'
```

The error :

[image]

In my main activity I'm using a call back method which uses the retrofit2 dependency

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
```

which is used by the below method

```
private void reverseGeocode(final Point point) {
        try {
            MapboxGeocoding client = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                    .accessToken(getString(R.string.access_token))
                    .query(Point.fromLngLat(point.longitude(), point.latitude()))
                    .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_ADDRESS)
                    .build();

            client.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {

                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();
                        if (results.size() > 0) {
                            CarmenFeature feature = results.get(0);

// If the geocoder returns a result, we take the first in the list and show a Toast with the place name.
                            mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                                @Override
                                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                                    if (style.getLayer(DROPPED_MARKER_LAYER_ID) != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                String.format(getString(R.string.location_picker_place_name_result),
                                                        feature.placeName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    getString(R.string.location_picker_dropped_marker_snippet_no_results), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    Timber.e("Geocoding Failure: %s", throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
            Timber.e("Error geocoding: %s", servicesException.toString());
            servicesException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And in the above picture, error class has these imports

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.LruCache;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
```

There might be a chance that these dependencies are clashing but I'm not sure, I'm guessing at this point.

But guaranteed that the above Picasso dependency only keeps popping when I add the map box dependencies, if not they do not display.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is fresh out of the oven and I honestly don't know yet why it works or what caused it, but it appears that when you add MapBox's navigation dependencies it updates your Picasso dependency as well (crazy, I know, but please bare with me).

The symptoms I got were basically two, the first one was a complete failure when trying to get the Picasso instance using `Picasso.with(context)`. So, it appears that that way of getting the instance is actually deprecated since version 2.71828, or at least [these docs say so](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library#loading-an-image-from-url) (and it works too), now it is just `Picasso.get()`

The second symptom I got was a problem with all Target objects, the old and faithful `onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)` method had its signature changed to include an Exception object as first argument, making it `onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable)`.

Now, once I noticed this pattern and simply updated all failing Picasso calls I was finally able to build my app with MapBox's dependencies and have all the old functionality untouched.

Now, as I mentioned, I honestly don't know why this happens, there's clearly something that MapBox does under the hood that forces Picasso to update to its latest version, or at least it looks like it in my case.

For the time being I got it to work like this, but any thoughts on why this happens would be appreciated. I'll make sure to post them here if I find them myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I've found a solution. Try to add to your build.gradle this:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```